# How do I install Ruby with libyaml on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed ruby-1.9.3-p0 on my Ubuntu 11.10 wubi and then rubygems to get Rails set up.

This is my code:

```
sudo ruby setup.rb
```

I got this error:

```
"/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in'<top(required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output). 
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby."
```

I installed libyaml and reinstalled Ruby but still it doesn't work.
The information changed and I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: since the information changed, could you post the new error you're getting?

Comment: How did you install ruby?  Installing libyaml and then installing a dpkg likely wouldn't have any effect, since it want's libyaml for the compile and the dpkg is a pre-built binary.  Try installing ruby from source instead. For that I suggest using rbenv and ruby-build (search on github).

Answer (score 56):

You must install the paquage libyaml-dev before installing ruby, if not you can still use extconf.rb for the missing library. So for this problem you can do (from the ruby install folder) :

```
cd ext/psych
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Extconf.rb is usefull for adding a library after have installed ruby.

Comment: This is the most amazing comment I've ever read on StackOverflow. I just got done compiling Ruby forever and was worried I'd need to redo all of that after installing libyaml. This is the exact solution I needed! Thank you!

Comment: I agree completely with @whalesalad 
This was one of the most useful things ever. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 14):

Do the following:

1. you must have "curl" installed :`sudo apt-get install curl`
2. Go To this link [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/)
3. Copy the command in the quick install  box and Paste it in your command prompt
4. Type `echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc`
5. Type `~/.bashrc`
6. Type the following code:
   `sudo apt-get install build-essential libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion`
7. Type: `rvm install 1.9.3-p0`
8. Type: `rvm use 1.9.3-p0`
9. Type: `gem install rails`
10. Have fun :)

Comment: worked for me.. except step 5. On some distros you need to type `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I get the same error, because when I install RVM, he uninstall libreadline, libyaml, etc.  then when I install that libraries, RVM is uninstall, and I get a beautiful deadlock.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, after a failed attempt at installing RoR on my Ubuntu 11.10 box, I combined the tips from this page and from this resource: http://www.thegeekwork.com/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/

This is the breakdown, step-by-step of what I just did to make this work (sorry if I didn't format this so great, I was just trying to keep it neat):

1) Fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10

2) `me@Box:~$ sudo apt-get install curl`

3) `me@Box:~$ sudo apt-get install git`

4) `me@Box:~$ sudo apt-get update`

5) `me@Box:~$ sudo apt-get dist-update`

6) `me@Box:~$ sudo shutdown -r now`

7) `me@Box:~$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)`

8) `me@Box:~$ gedit ~/.bashrc`

9) add the following line to the end (and save the file)

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

10) `me@Box:~$ source ~/.bashrc`

11) `me@Box:~$ type rvm | head -1`

After executing above command you should be getting this output -
rvm is a function

You’ve successfully installed the RVM. Next, you are supposed to install additional dependencies. To find out those programs type -

12) `me@Box:~$ rvm requirements`

After the above command, install the additional packages recommended by RVM -

13) `me@Box:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion`

14) `me@Box:~$ rvm install 1.9.2`

(#14 takes a little while)

15) `me@Box:~$ rvm use 1.9.2`

(This selects the version you want to use)

(If you aren’t sure about the ruby version currently being used, then type -
ruby -v)

16) `me@Box:~$ gem install rails`

(this will take a little while...)

17) Make a sample application as a test...

`me@Box:~$ rails new test_app`

`me@Box:~$ cd test_app`

`me@Box:~/test_app$ rails server`

AND THAT"S WHERE THIS THING DIDN"T WORK. ARRRRRRRRRrrrrrrrrrrrrrgh.

So,

18) in your application folder ("test_app"), open Gemfile and uncomment "therubyracer" line

19) `me@Box:~/test_app$ bundle install`

20) `me@Box:~/test_app$ rails server`

Done, and done.

I don't understand why it set 0.0.0.0:3000 as the host address (I thought it would be 127.0.0.1), but quite frankly, that's not bothering me right now -- I got it to work (so far).  Time to get going with some Rails! :D

I hope this helps anyone else who is looking to make this work! :)

Note: I realize that #13 repeats some of the things I already installed, but I don't care, I'm just doing what the thing says. :/

Note2: Holy learning curve on just posting an answer!  I wasn't sure what was considered "code" and apparently the prompt is considered code.  Makes sense now :)

Note3: This is my first "Answer" on StackOverflow! :D

Answer (score 5):

If you are compiling ruby you might need libyaml-dev

Comment: Compiled on OpenSuse and ruby didn't stop complaining about missing libyaml. Now it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Debian (and Ubuntu, etc.) packages that contain the files needed to install some other program from source usually end in `-dev`, e.g. `libyaml-dev`, so try installing that. Or just use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/), it will actually install this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Compling yaml from its source will make it work. I am running the same config as yours. I followed this http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/10/31/install-ruby-193-with-libyaml-on-centos/. It definitely works.